# Visual studio 2013 Nuget changes project files on startup

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, nuget

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and i'm working in a solution that contains over 100 projects. When i open this solution Visual Studio edits every project file with the following code :

```
    <RestorePackages>true</RestorePackages>

    <Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets" Condition="Exists('$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets')" />
      <Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
        <PropertyGroup>
          <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
        </PropertyGroup>
        <Error Condition="!Exists('$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets')"         Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)',         '$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets'))" />
      </Target>
```

What's strange is that i am the only one with this problem of those who are working on this project. ( I am the last one who joined them tho ).

I am using the following extensions for my VS:

1. Latest version of VS2013 SP.
2. NodeJS v1.0
3. NuGet Package Manager v.2.8.60610.756
4. PostSharp v4.1.23
5. ReSharper Ultimate v3.0

We are using TFS for our source control.

And when i'm building the solution ( when i get the change to ) i get into a NuGet Restore loop where it checks if i already have the package or not.

Comment: Not sure if this helps entirely - Is your **Tools.Options.NuGet Package Manager.Allow Nuget to download missing packages** enabled?  Disable if so.

Comment: I tried it both on and off  but the problem is the same @Micky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of Nuget are you using? This is happening because of using the old way of Nuget package restore (before v 2.7) in VS (i.e Right click VS solution and enable package restore). This will cause VS to edit the .CSPROJ file.

Beginning with NuGet 2.7, the NuGet Visual Studio extension integrates into Visual Studio's build events and restores missing packages when a build begins. This feature is enabled by default, but developers can opt out if desired. What the NuGet team is now recommending (when building within VS) is both a lot cleaner and a lot simpler. In short, you don't do anything special, and it just happens! This is because NuGet now always restores packages before building in VS. So no changes whatsoever are needed on your files, which is beautiful!

Ref: [Package Restore Nuget](http://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore)

[Package Restore Source](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2014/01/the-right-way-to-restore-nuget-packages.html)

Comment: I asume that my nuget is 2.8 while i'm using the package manager. 
Do you have an idea why i am the only one who has this problem while other don't have it?

Comment: Can you check if you have the following environment variable set to True "EnableNuGetPackageRestore"?